Vue.js Version finding program only returns a white screen
I did write a program to simply display the vue version. Not only i dont get the alert but all I get is a white screen. Im a beginner on javascript and I had installed latest version of nodejs and done programs on it. now I installed vue exactly how the vuejs site has told and it didnt seem to work. I cant find my mistake either but when i try the version of vue on cmd it shows the version correctly
this is my pgm. console log says Vue is not defined.
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
 
 <script>
 alert(`Vue.version = ${Vue.version}`);
  </script>
</html>

but when i try it on cmd using
vue --version
i get the correct version

https://unpkg.com/vue@next url is wrong and any other problems with vue are caused by it. It's https://unpkg.com/vue, check unpkg.com main page if you're unsure how to use it. Check Vue official docs either, they are extensive for a beginner, https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start#using-vue-from-cdn . vue command isn't relevant, it's Vue CLI package, the only way it's related to Vue framework is "vue" word in it

oioioi That solved it.Thanks sir. dang I feel like an idiot but hey its not my first time.
